# Sending Email's Using GoDaddy Hosting With PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm currently working on getting a website up and running for my Virtual Company, I have been researching and can't find the answer to this anywhere.

When a user Signs up, I want them to receive an email giving a brief outline of the company. Here is the code that I use (**And Yes, the $_SESSION Variables do have Values**)

```
<?php
session_start();

require '../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$EmailUsername = $_SESSION['Username'];
$EmailFirstName = $_SESSION['FirstName'];
$EmailEmail = $_SESSION['Email'];

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'no-reply@ozzietransport.org';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '#Password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                       // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('no-reply@ozzietransport.org', 'No-Reply');
$mail->addAddress($EmailEmail, $EmailFirstName);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('', '');
$mail->addCC('');
$mail->addBCC('');

$mail->addAttachment('');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Ozzie Transport Signup';
$mail->Body    =    "Hello, $EmailUsername.
                    <br><br>
                    Welcome to <b>Ozzie Transport.</b> A Virtual Trucking Company Utilising Truckers MP’s Multiplayer's Servers on Both American Truck Simulator and European Truck Simulator 2.
                    <br><br>
                    <b>Ozzie Transport</b> was founded by <i>Mr. Will Lads</i> and <i>Mr. Jacob Findlater</i>. Who where major assets to Ozzie Transport's Beginning.
                    <br><br>
                    Your Account is in the process of activation by our current Driver Manager. <i>Luc Jones</i>, You may log into your account using the Username and Password given in your Sign Up Application. 
                    <br><br>
                    <b>Username:</b> <i>$EmailUsername.</i>
                    <br><br>
                    <b><i>If you have any questions, please reply to this email. We would be happy to hear from you.</i></b>
                    <br><br>
                    <b>Kind Regards</b>
                    <br><b><i>Joshua Micallef<br>
                    Chief Executive Officer - Ozzie Transport
                    ";

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

session_destroy();
//header("Location: ../../Login.php");
```

Every time I run the code it gives me the following error Message: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting.

Anyone got any ideas, I believe there are still people wondering about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your GoDaddy account should give you the host name and port number you need to connect to for your hosting account so you can email out using their email servers.

It will look something like this but you'll have to check with GoDaddy for exact settings for your account.

```
SMTP_SERVER: smtpout.secureserver.net (or alternatively relay-hosting.secureserver.net)
SMTP_PORT: 465 //or 3535 or 80 or 25
SMTP_AUTH: true //always
SMTP_Secure: 'ssl' //only if using port 465
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I should have also noted that I was able to send emails on my localhost server using Gmail, however, was not able to on the official website. These settings don't seem to change anything for me, I'll open a support ticket with them and see what they have to say. Thanks for your lightning fast response,

Comment: You might be able to find the correct settings somewhere in your hosting account once you're logged in.

Answer (score 0):

For others that have the same problem as did the configuration that works today is (note the `SMTPAuth = false` and `SMTPAutoTLS = false`:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host        = 'localhost;
$mail->SMTPAuth    = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Username    = 'no-reply@example.com';
$mail->Password    = '*******';
$mail->Port        = 25;
```

You can check current PHPMailers [docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#godaddy).